# Building a stack using two queues with javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Can anyone show me how to construct a stack using two queues with javascript? (using linked lists).
I can implement a stack. I can implement a queue. But I'm struggling to figure out how I would use the queue to build the stack.

```
class Stack {
    constructor() {}
    push() {

    }
    pop() {}
}

class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    enqueue(data) {
        var node = new Node(data);

        if (!this.first) {
            this.first = node;
            this.last = node;
        } else {
            this.last.next = node;
            this.last = node;
        }

        return ++this.size;
    }

    dequeue() {
        if (!this.first) return null;

        var temp = this.first;
        if (this.first == this.last) {
            this.last = null;
        }
        this.first = this.first.next;
        this.size--;
        return temp.value;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use the push and pop methods on the stack. This is not homework or anything. It's just personal development. If anyone can help, a little explanation would be much appreciated as well. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-stack-using-queue/

Comment: with minor changes you can try something like this https://jsbin.com/cazenipare/edit?js,console

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you. This was really helpful

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you so much. You are a star. I see now how it works. Thanks again.